# TileMill CartoCSS marker-file url

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I have noticed `shape://arrow` in the `highway.mss` file ([line 244](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/blob/master/examples/open-streets-dc/highway.mss#L244)) in the Open Streets DC TileMill examples.

Where in the directory structure is this url pointing to? How does this url work to get the arrow symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a [Mapnik reference](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/API-changes-between-v2.0-and-v2.1).

CartoCSS is actually [converted into an XML format that Mapnik uses](http://www.macwright.org/presentations/carto-foss4g/#25) to render the stylings of the map.

And it looks like the built-in arrow marker type "may" (their word not mine) now be referenced by `shape://arrow`.  This being the new way to symbolize the marker as either an `arrow` (`shape://arrow`) or an `ellipse` (`shape://ellipse`), replacing [`MarkersSymbolizer` `marker-type`](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MarkersSymbolizer).

Comment: Great. Do you know if there is further documentation/reference to list what markers are available without defining your own? It seems that the `shape://...` syntax isn't documented so well